# not able to use Element.requestFullscreen() in typescript for different browsers

Tags: typescript, html5-fullscreen

I am trying to use [javascript fullscreen Api](http://w3schools-fa.ir/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.html) in my React-Typescript project, to display a div content in fullscreen mode when required. My code looks like below,

```
var elem = document.getElementById("MyDiv");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
 }
```

This works fine in chrome, but to support multiple browsers, I need to use other functions like,

````
if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }```

When I am trying to use these functions in typescript, it is giving me a compile-time error saying  "Property 'mozRequestFullScreen' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'".

Can anyone help me to solve this compile-time error, and use fullscreen API for all browsers?
````

Answer (score 1):

According to MS, Typescript has removed vendor DOM API support in `lib.d.ts` from `v3.1`. They recommend to add the type on your own app if your runtime guarantees these APIs name available for example:

for IE create the file `dom.ie.d.ts`:

```
interface Element {
  msRequestFullscreen(): void;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Can you please tell me, what can I do with the Mozilla firebox, Safari? Do I have to create a separate file for that? If yes, what will be the name of that file?

Comment: Yeah I think so. They are supposed to be different files such as `dom.safari.d.ts`, `dom.firefox.d.ts`

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about this answer? Where should that file go? Should anything be written in that commented `...` section? Is this the entire file? Do I need to import the `Element` interface in the `ts` file where I am writing this code and want to request fullscreen access? Thanks! @JSDrogon and @tmhao2005

Answer (score 0):

Under similar circumstance I opted for using useRef to get the video Element.
Then in the above example you can substitute element for

```
if (yourElementRef.current.requestFullscreen) {
  yourElement.current.requestFullscreen();
}
```

and that will remove the warning from Typescript. Notice the current